# Changing install directory?

Tags: wallets, accounts, windows, datadir

My Windows drive is almost full. As I actually have two drives, I want to move the blockchain from the default location to the second drive. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

when you run geth use the option `--datadir` to specify where to download the blockchain.